# Il décline ses contenus

Tags: sens

Le titre de [la page twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/LeTemps?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) du journal suisse ‘Le Temps’ est :

> Site suisse d’information. Il décline ses contenus avec exigence et indépendance.

Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire ‘Il décline ses contenus’ dans ce contexte ?

La signification la plus proche que j’ai trouvé est ‘break things down’ mais je ne pense pas que ça s’applique dans ce cas.

Answer (score 2):

C'est sans doute le sens d'[*énoncer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cliner/2), *exposer*, avec l'idée de variantes ; un site consacré à l'information qui *présente divers* contenus de telle manière (*...avec exigence et indépendance*).

Answer (score 1):

Décliner peut avoir le sens de "présenter sous différentes formes". C'est un sens proche des déclinaisons grammaticales où un radical revêt différentes formes suivant le genre, la fonction grammaticale, etc.

Ici, par métaphore, le radical serait la ligne éditoriale et les articles, le contenu, des déclinaisons de cette dernière.